# Getting data from a website from a unique html class

Tags: html, web-scraping

How am I able to get specific data from a website? If it helps then the data I need is labeled under a unique html class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a web page.
2. Make it a DOM structure.
3. Traverse it with xPath: `//*[@class='target_class']`
4. Output results.

If you share a language that you use, I may give you some posts with examples. For *php* read [here](http://scraping.pro/using-domxpath-for-parsing-page-content-in-php/).

Comment: I can use PHP but I prefer Python

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beautifulsoup to do what you want in python.You can scrape data from a specific html class.See here http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/